# NLog framework FileName path to specific folder

Tags: logging, frameworks, nlog

Hi Team,
                       I am using NLog framework for logging and got struck up at one point i.e. I found the NLog config allows only to store the log file to the application folder where NLog is stored followed by folder name specified as below.

Well my application requirement is that it should be to a specific folder and at the same time it should be configurable. Is there a way I could by some means set the fileName="C:\Myfolder\Log\log.txt". Any pointers\suggestions on this would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I could found solution by simply placing the fileName="c:\Logs\Trace-MyDB-Log Start Date ${shortdate:format=s}.txt" in config.

Wondersing if there is a provesion for detecting Drive as it's not always c:\ drive where it will be installed.